# String constructor to handle byte array producing weird result

Tags: java, string, byte

I am using implicit String constructor that handle byte array..but it results weird. Do I have to do something more for proper output..? Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code..

```
    byte[] arr = { 23, 34, 20, 65, 88, 95 };

    String s1 = new String(arr);
    System.out.println("First: "+s1);

    String s2 = new String(arr, 1, 3);
    System.out.println("Second: "+s2);
```

it prints:

> First: ?"?AX_
>
> Second: ?AX

Comment: What is your expected output?  23 and 20 aren't printable characters, 34 is `"`, 65 is `A`, 88 is `X`, and 95 is `_`.

Comment: @rgettman:Yes you are right, I just tried it Starting with 65 as my books example did and it prints well..but how is that happening

Comment: Protip: get in the habit of explicitly *specifying* the encoding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String()` constructor you are using is interpreting the bytes in the array according to the *default character set* for your Java environment. That can differ.

If you have a specific character encoding that you want to use, like "US-ASCII" or "UTF-8", then you should specify the character set using a different constructor, such as: [String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Those are the characters for the codes that you provided. If you change your byte array to this, you'll see characters a-f:

```
byte[] arr = { 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102 };
```